# How to conduct dominance analysis with a large number of predictors?

Tags: multiple-regression

I'm attempting to conduct a dominance analysis on a linear regression model with about 25 predictors.

Specifically, I'm using the `relaimpo` package.
https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v017i01

I believe the function estimates the average incremental variance of a predictor over all possible orders of predictor entry. That said, I might be misunderstanding something.

Thus, this procedure is only computationally tractable for a small number of predictors. Perhaps up to 20 or so.

Thus, I was wondering what people do when they want to apply this method to models with more predictors. Is there a standard way of sampling predictor sets/orderings? Is there an R package that implements this?

Answer (score 3):

This post suggests that the computational challenges of standard dominance analysis (or "Shapley Regression") are well known as computational time grows exponentially with the number of predictors. Instead, a popular alternative is to perform "relative weights" analysis given that simulations suggest that this generally produces very similar results, but is computationally tractable with many more predictors.

https://www.displayr.com/shapley-vs-relative-weights/

> Shapley regression and Relative Weights are two methods for estimating
>   the importance of predictor variables in linear regression. Studies
>   have shown that the two, despite being constructed in very different
>   ways, provide surprisingly similar scores((Grömping, U. (2015).
>   Variable importance in regression models, WIREs Comput Stat 7,
>   137-152.))((Lebreton, J.M., Ployhart, R.E., & Ladd, R.T. (2004). A
>   Monte Carlo Comparison of Relative Importance Methodologies.
>   Organizational Research Methods 7, 258 - 282.)). As the computational
>   expense of Shapley regression by far outweighs that of Relative
>   weights, and if the two yield essentially the same results, then you
>   can consider Relative Weights a strong alternative to Shapley. In this
>   blog post, I explore the relationship between the two methods.

This post provides an [example of conducting a Relative Weights analysis in R](https://www.displayr.com/reasons-to-use-relative-weights/).  It uses the flipRegression package on github: https://github.com/Displayr/flipRegression
Warning: The package seems to have a lot of dependencies.

The `relaimpo` package also has the `genizi` and `car` estimates of relative importance. These are alternative methods for decomposing variance explained across predictor variables. They can be requested using the `type` argument.

```
relaimpo:::calc.relimp(fit, type = c("car", "genizi"))
```

I've done a quick comparison of few linear models with 10 or so predictors and results were fairly similar for `car` and `genizi` to those obtained using "lmg" (note `lmg` is the default computationally demanding approach). E.g., coefficients correlating r = .9992. And on a model with 25 highly correlated predictors "car" and "genizi" obtained relative importance estimates that correlated r = .994. That said, it'd be good to identify some more thorough simulation studies.